# Simple glyph and cypher

Tags: cipher, password

A spy acquired a microfilm containing the list of clues that he can decode to complete the hinted message in the password for opening the electronic vault of old records. What is the password?

Microfim:

[image]

Message:

_ _ _ N O _ _ _ _ A R T _ _ _ _ _ _ _ I S _ _ _ _ _ _ K E Y

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> LENNONMCCARTNEYHARRISONSTARKEY

The clues in the microfilm are

> not written in Semaphore or a variant, but a neat shaped-alike visual cipher. They decode to names of Beatles songs: 1. Dr Robert, 2. Taxman, 3. Polythene Pam, and so on. Old records indeed!
>
>  
>   
>  [image]

Comment: Right..and it's good to have you in Puzzling